# Drawing logic gates in LaTeX

Tags: circuitikz, logic

[image]
How do I draw (i) and (iii) in the above image?

**In (i), I am not able to write the variable a and texts just right to the image.

In (ii), I am not able to create n number of inputs in a circuit.**

Comment: Give a starting code.

Comment: Ok, you told what you were not able to do. Now show what you were able to do. Share a Minimal Working Example of what you already did, in order to get relevant help without forcing helpers to do all of it from scratch ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Here's how I would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        % Gates
        \node[and port, no input leads] (A) at (0, 0) {};
        \node[and port, no input leads] (B) at (0, -1.5) {};
        \node[and port, number inputs=5] (C) at (0, -3) {};
        \node[or port, number inputs=5] (D) at (0, -4.5) {};
        
        % Single inputs
        \draw ($(A.in 1)!0.5!(A.in 2)$) -- (A.left);
        \draw ($(B.in 1)!0.5!(B.in 2)$) -- (B.left);
        
        % identity labels
        \node[left] at ($(A.in 1)!0.5!(A.in 2)$) {\(a\)};
        \node[right] at (A.out) {\(a\)};
        
        % NOT labels
        \node at (B) [ocirc] {};
        \node[left] at ($(B.in 1)!0.5!(B.in 2)$) {\(a\)};
        \node[right] at (B.out) {\(a'\)};
        
        % AND labels
        \node[left] at (C.in 1) {\(a_1\)};
        \node[left] at (C.in 2) {\(a_2\)};
        \node[left] at ($(C.in 3) + (0, -0.05)$) {\(\vdots\)};
        \node[left] at (C.in 5) {\(a_n\)};
        \node[right] at (C.out) {\(a_1a_2\dotsm a_n\)};
        
        % OR labels
        \node[left] at (D.in 1) {\(a_1\)};
        \node[left] at (D.in 2) {\(a_2\)};
        \node[left] at ($(D.in 3) + (0, -0.05)$) {\(\vdots\)};
        \node[left] at (D.in 5) {\(a_n\)};
        \node[right] at (D.out) {\(a_1 + a_2 + \dotsb a_n\)};
        
        % Gate labels
        \node[right] at ($(A.out) + (3, 0)$) {\textbf{Identity-Gate} (symbolises \(x\));};
        \node[right] at ($(B.out) + (3, 0)$) {\textbf{NOT-Gate} (or \textbf{inverter}) (symbolises \(x'\));};
        \node[right] at ($(C.out) + (3, 0)$) {\textbf{AND-Gate} (symbolises \(x_1x_2\dotsm x_n\));};
        \node[right] at ($(D.out) + (3, 0)$) {\textbf{OR-Gate} (symbolises \(x_1 + x_2 + \dotsb + x_n\));};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

I couldn't find an easy way to do a single input gate of the same style so its a double input gate with the inputs hidden and a new input drawn half way between the two using the `(A.left)` node and the `calc` libraries `(A)!0.5!(B)` syntax to draw nodes halfway between `(A)` and `(B)`. For the text naming each gate its simply a node attached to the output of the gate and then shifted to the right using the `calc` library syntax `($(A) + (3, 0)$)` for a point 3 to the right of `(A)`.
For the input/output labels each node is named and you can use this to attach a node.
Finally the 'NOT' gate is just an and gate with no inputs drawn and a single input added and a circle drawn on the output to denote an inversion.

## Syntax Explanation

### Gate Options

The options for the gates that are used here are as follows:

- `and port` - This is an AND gate (also used for the identity and NOT gate)
- `or port` - This is an OR gate
- `no input leads`  - Hide the input leads, this is used on the identity and NOT gates as they have only a single lead which I've drawn manually.
- `number of inputs=n` - Draw the logic gate with `n` inputs (the default is `n=2`)

### Nodes

In `tikz` one can create a node using `\node (A) at (x, y) {};`.
This creates a node called `(A)` at the point `(x, y)`. Nodes are also created automatically when you place symbols in `circuitikz`. Of particular interest are the nodes created by logic gates. When placing the gate we give it a name, here I've just used `(A)`, `(B)`, `(C)` and `(D)` but for a larger image more descriptive names may be useful. As well as these nodes which are the gates there are also input and output nodes and other nodes referring to various points on the gates. In this case we use `(A.left)` (note that is a full stop/period, not a comma) which gives the left middle of the gate (where the input meets the gate for the identity gate and not gate in the image). Similarly we can use `(A.in i)` where `i` is a number when we have multiple inputs (so `(A.in 1)` is the top input, `(A.in 2)` is the second from the top etc.). We also make use of `(A.out)` which is the output of the gate. For more detail on the nodes created by a logic gate see the [circuitikz manual](https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf), in particular section 3.24.5.2 "American logic port anchors" page 124.

### Calc Library

There are also two bits of syntax from the `calc` library which extends `tikz`.
The first is the following

```
(A)!x!(B)
```

where `x` is some value between 0 and 1 and `(A)` and `(B)` are nodes. What this does is defines the point on the line from `(A)` to `(B)` such that the point is `x` along the line, in our case we use `x = 0.5` so we get the midpoint of the line connecting `(A)` and `(B)`.

The second bit of syntax is

```
($(A) + (x, y)$)
```

which is simple vector addition. This allows us to take the point `(A)` and define a point that is `x` units to the right and `y` units up.
For more detail on the `calc` library see the [Tikz manual](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) in particular section 13.5 "Coordinate Calculations" page 148.
Also [this](https://faculty.cord.edu/ahendric/tex/TikZcheatsheet.pdf) cheat sheet has lots of similar syntax that is often useful.

Comment: nice, +1. You have `(A.left)` for the central point in the body, but yes, there is no corresponding one at input distance. You would have much more flexibility with `ieee` logic port shapes.

Comment: Yes I did think about using `ieee` but I'm (slightly) more familiar with `circuitikz` and that's how the question is tagged. If someone wants to add `ieee` as another answer that would be fine. I'll change it to use `(A.left)`.

Comment: @Willoughby compiler is taking too much time to run this code. I've been waiting for 30 mins to get the result!!! :-(

Comment: It compiles fine for me copying and pasting into a new document. Make sure that you have the required packages installed, sometimes that causes compilation to hang. Also check that you have all the commands correct, in particular the semicolons. Missing semicolons can make Tikz never finish compiling. If that doesn't work does other similar code compile, maybe try just drawing a single component.

Comment: I am actually pretty new to circuit diagram. So I don't know what `no input leads, (A,left),(A)!0.5!(B)` actually do. I am learning by watching videos in you tube. But there are not sufficient videos on you tube. Would you like to please elaborate those functions?

Comment: @Willoughby sorry I meant the IEEE logic port shapes in `circuitikz`... ;-) I know nothing of the standard Tikz electric library...

Comment: @ManjoyDas what about reading the manual? And I kindly suggest to go through the tutorials, both of `circuitikz` and Ti*k*Z

Comment: I thought that I wouldn't give any thanksgiving for this answer as  accepting the answer is equivalent to this. But really I couldn't check myself from writing this as the syntax, commands are so beautifully described by @Willoughby . thank you